# Multiple factory methods versus single method

Tags: java, class, factory, factory-method, construction

Is it better to use a single factory method and a general constructor for all instances, then populate the instances? OR should multiple factory methods and constructors be used instead? What are the advantages to each approach?

For example (**Option #1**):

```
VehicleFactory {
  Vehicle createVehicle(int serialNo);
}

// assuming that Car and Plane are of type Vehicle:

Car car = (Car)VehicleFactory.createVehicle(serialNo1);
car.setCarSpecificField1(...);
car.setCarSpecificField2(...);

Plane plane = (Plane)VehicleFactory.createVehicle(serialNo2);
plane.setPlaneSpecificField1(...);
plane.setPlaneSpecificField2(...);
```

Here Plane and Car will have a simple general constructor, but would require multiple setters and getters. The caller would have to populate the instances.

Or (**Option #2**):

```
VehicleFactory {
  Car createCar(int serialNo, CarSpecificField1 field1, CarSpecificField2 field2, ...)
  Plane createPlane(int serialNo, PlaneSpecificField1 field1, PlaneSpecificField2, ...)
}

Car car = VehicleFactory.createCar(serialNo1, carSpecificField1, ...);
Plane plane = VehicleFactory.createPlane(serialNo2, planeSpecificField1, ...);
```

Here, we don't need getter and setters but would need different constructors for each instance.

Comment: Consider using a Builder pattern.

Comment: The Builder pattern seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, but keep in mind that inheriting builder methods from a superclass means you must set all car-specific fields first (or do lots of casting).

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    Object vehicleSpecificField1, vehicleSpecificField2;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    Object carSpecificField;

    Car(final Object vehicleSpecificField1, final Object vehicleSpecificField2, final Object carSpecificField) {
        this.vehicleSpecificField1 = vehicleSpecificField1;
        this.vehicleSpecificField2 = vehicleSpecificField2;
        this.carSpecificField = carSpecificField;
    }
}

abstract class VehicleBuilder<E extends Vehicle> {
    Object vehicleSpecificField1, vehicleSpecificField2;

    public VehicleBuilder<E> vehicleSpecificField1(final Object vehicleSpecificField1) {
        this.vehicleSpecificField1 = vehicleSpecificField1;
        return this;
    }

    public VehicleBuilder<E> vehicleSpecificField2(final Object vehicleSpecificField2) {
        this.vehicleSpecificField2 = vehicleSpecificField2;
        return this;
    }

    abstract E create();

}

class CarBuilder extends VehicleBuilder<Car> {
    Object carSpecificField;

    public CarBuilder carSpecificField(final Object carSpecificField) {
        this.carSpecificField = carSpecificField;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    Car create() {
        return new Car(vehicleSpecificField1, vehicleSpecificField2, carSpecificField);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car = new CarBuilder().carSpecificField("car").vehicleSpecificField1("foo").vehicleSpecificField2("bar").create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
VehicleFactory<E extends Vehicle> {
    E getVehicle(int serialNo, VehicleProperty<E> ... args);
}
CarFactory extends VehicleFactory<Car>{
    @Override
    Car getVehicle(int serialNo, VehicleProperty<Car> ... args);
}

VehicleProperty<E extends Vehicle>{ /* getters and setters */}
CarProperty extends VehicleProperty<Car>{}
```